# What characters arent allowed in a JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, php, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

So after receiving my response, I keep getting a parse error. Is there such thing as illegal characters?

Here is the response

```
[{"businessID": ChIJ49DlQ5NiwokRQ_noyKqlchQ,"latitude": 40.733038,"longitude":-73.6840691,"address":"1201
Jericho Turnpike, New Hyde Park","businessname":"SUBWAY®Restaurants"},{"businessID": ChIJZfl6R5NiwokRZo7PU4NPoMY
,"latitude": 40.7329359,"longitude":-73.684513,"address":"1113 Jericho Turnpike, New Hyde Park","businessname"
:"Gino's"},{"businessID": ChIJcbpnRJNiwokRrtbOKe7HQo0,"latitude": 40.733049,"longitude":-73.684006,"address"
:"1203 Jericho Turnpike, New Hyde Park","businessname":"Wong's Garden"},]
```

Here is my function that handles the response. I know for sure its breaking before the alert because the alert is not being triggered

```
var datad = $(msg).text();
    console.log(datad);
    var resultstring = datad.replace(',]',']');
    var JsonParseData = JSON.parse(resultstring);
        alert(JsonParseData); ///BREAKING BEFORE THIS LINE
```

Comment: double quote the value of businessID in the object

Comment: also there's a trailing comma

Comment: @AnthonySottile Im removing the comma at line....var resultstring = datad.replace(',]',']');

Comment: Java is not Javascript.  Please be careful about using the right tag.  I've fixed it.

Comment: Looks like you have random new line chars in "address" part and missing quotation marks in variable resultstring, in "businessID" part. You can check the JSON formatting here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

Comment: @ajb sorry about that. I meant javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of mistakes.

1. Need to puth the string in double quotes(`"`). Replace `"businessID": ChIJ49DlQ5NiwokRQ_noyKqlchQ` with `"businessID":"ChIJ49DlQ5NiwokRQ_noyKqlchQ"`
2. Remove the `,` at the end of following line `"businessname":"Wong's Garden"},]`

Answer (score 2):

The key values of JSON require quotation marks. You have fewer quotes in the JSON data, and at last you have one more comma and one more carriage return

like this is right:

`[{"businessID":"ChIJ49DlQ5NiwokRQ_noyKqlchQ","latitude":"40.733038","longitude":"-73.6840691","address":"1201 Jericho Turnpike, New Hyde Park","businessname":"SUBWAY®Restaurants"},{"businessID":"ChIJZfl6R5NiwokRZo7PU4NPoMY","latitude":"40.7329359","longitude":"-73.684513","address":"1113 Jericho Turnpike, New Hyde Park","businessname":"Gino's"},{"businessID":"ChIJcbpnRJNiwokRrtbOKe7HQo0","latitude":"40.733049","longitude":"-73.684006","address":"1203 Jericho Turnpike, New Hyde Park","businessname":"Wong's Garden"}]`

Comment: Why did you put the numbers in quotes?

Comment: oo, sorry, Numbers don't need Quotes

Answer (score 1):

Your response is an invalid json format for 2 reasons:

- The values of the "businessID" requires quotation marks.
- There should not be a comma after the last object of the JSON (your replace string function fix this).

I recommend you to use this JSON toolkits:

- http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ (This orders my json although is incorrect)
- https://jsonformatter.org/ (I use this a lot, my favorite)